# bpy.ops.render.render does not find camera

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to run the following smallscript. The preview with 12 does render, but the last line of the script fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Programme\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Cannot render, no camera
```

But there is a camera

```
import bpy

def reset_scene():
    for item in bpy.data.objects:
        item.select = True

    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    for material in bpy.data.materials:
        if not material.users:
            bpy.data.materials.remove(material)

    for texture in bpy.data.textures:
        if not texture.users:
            bpy.data.textures.remove(texture)

reset_scene()


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0,1,0))

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0,-0.05,0))

bpy.context.object.scale[1] = 0.1
bpy.context.object.scale[0] = 10
bpy.context.object.scale[2] = 10

bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(0, 4, 4), rotation=(-0.7853, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SUN', location=(0, 5, 0))

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = 'c:\test.jpg'
bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

When I set the camera explicitly with this script:

```
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
```

it seems to work.

**Why can't it find the camera automatically like when you press F12?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply set the scene.camera after you add the camera.

```
from bpy import context
scene = context.scene

...

bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(0, 4, 4), 
                          rotation=(-0.7853, 0, 0))
scene.camera = context.object
...
```

Hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> invokes the operator, which  when `scene.camera is None` , throws a message if no cam, or uses a camera from the scene and sets it to `scene.camera`.  Test by adding a few cameras, setting `scene.camera` to None, and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

To invoke the operator from code,

```
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', write_still=True)
```

Note: `bpy.data` contains **all** the objects in the blend file. `context.scene.objects` contains all the objects in the context scene.  The context scene may not necessarily be `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]`. `render.render` renders the context scene, unless another scene is specified.

A tip, set up a `context` variable, either `context = bpy.context` or `from bpy import context` at the beginning of your test code, then later cut and paste into, for instance, operator `execute(self, context)` methods. Setting vars like  `scene = context.scene`, `obj = context.object`, `obj.scale = (0.1, 1, 10)` makes code far more readable IMO rather than always addressing from `bpy`.

Comment: Dear batFINGER, just a big thank you from someone who has been learning Blender (and 3D graphics) without formal training, but with the help of Google, which so so so often has led me (and my friends) to your contributions!

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I'm still getting `Error: Cannot render, no camera`.